# MutationObserver observe jquery append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code works on page load but it is never fires when I insert an element (div) to the DOM with jquery.append()

Is there any way to catch with MutationObserver when an element has been added?

here is my code

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
     mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
          if($(mutation.target).length > 0){
               if($(mutation.target).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() === 'img'){
                    console.log('IMG ADDED', $(mutation.target));   
               }
           }   
     });        
});
observer.observe(document,{subtree:true, attributes:true, characterData:true});
```

Comment: Wouldn't you know when you insert an element, Mutations are rarely the way to go ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I figured it out... Thought I would post to save someone the headache..

I needed **childList:true** as well

```
observer.observe(document,{childList:true, subtree:true, attributes:true, characterData:true});
```